# Applying material to models exported from Blender in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, mesh

I'm fairly new to Unity and Blender so theres a fair chance this is something simple that I'm just unaware of.

[image]

In the above image, the model on the left is a scaled Cube created in Unity with a material applied. This one is displaying correctly (the image is fitting the size of the model).
On the right is a model created in Blender then exported as a FBX file before being imported into Unity and having the same material applied.

I've spend the last few hours playing with all the settings I can think of in Unity but I can't find anything that affects the way the material is applied to the imported model.

What is the correct way to export a model from Blender/what is the correct way to apply a material to an imported model to ensure the material is displayed correctly?

The way its rendering is making me think Unity is treating the model as being many times larger than what its rendered.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: did you create a [UV map](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics) in Blender?

Comment: Thank you very much @derHugo, that was exactly the problem. I knew it would be something simple but with my limited 3D experience it wasn't obvious.